# Opa: Nodejs not found

Tags: windows, node.js, open-source, cygwin, opa

I get the following message while trying to **./configure opa_v2980** using Cygwin in Windows XP 32-bit:

> Checking for nodejs... Not found

I've already successfully installed nodejs in Cygwin using the following steps outlined by [Schalk Neethling](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2011/10/10/installing-node-js-on-windows/):

1. Installed git, python, g++, openssl and make packages
2. Cloned nodejs
3. Built it
4. Tested the installation. When I first tried to test the node installation, I got the following message:

> "bash: node: command not found"

so I added the following path to where nodejs is installed and the test worked:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/github/nodejs
```

However, Im wondering whether the path has anything to do with this Nodejs not found error I am now getting?

Comment: Why don't you use node.js installation native for windows?

Comment: I did as you said, I installed the Windows Installer (node-v0.8.4-x86.msi), it installed nodejs successfully, but when I ran ./configure inside the opa_v2980 directory, I still get "Checking for nodejs... Not found". Is this error replated to the path not correctly set?

Comment: I don't know node.js native can work on cygwin or not (I think you must compile node in cygwin...). What is opa_v2980? If you want to use node, just open 'cmd' and use node.

Comment: opa_v2980 is the latest version of [Opa](http://opalang.org/get.xmlt#opalang_night_view=tar-gz;opalang_package_view=nightly) for Windows. I've already compiled it in cygwin and the test worked. But now Im getting ready to compile Opa and I'm getting this message

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood your question :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source repository cannot be easily compiled with windows yet (the situation will probably change soon).
We used to have a cygwin port and we have an up to date msys port but it is not public yet. It required some amount of work to achieve these ports, so I can say that your chance are very poor to succeed, even if the nodejs backend simplifies things now.

If you don't need to modify the compiler, you should use the binary package (yes I know it is 64bit only).

My advice: either wait and ask on the mailing list (so you can get friends) for the windows msys port OR invest time to get a 64bit machine (true or emulated via KQEMU)